# How to limit execution of nested sql by if

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm in process of migrating data. I have two tables linked with foreign key as below

```
master_table
------------
OldId char  -- Old Primary key 
Id    int   -- New Primary Key
....

detail_table
------------
Id    int
old_master_table_id char  -- old FK from master_table
master_table_id     int   -- new FK from master_table
....
```

What I need to do is fill `detail_table.master_table_id` with `Id` from `master_table` and delete `old_master_table_id` and `OldId`. I'm using following Update command and then dropping column. this command works fine for the first time. however I need to limit he execution of commands so it only run if the old columns are there.

```
IF NOT Exists(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE 
  Object_ID = Object_ID('detail_table') AND Name = 'old_master_table_id') BEGIN
    UPDATE detail_table SET 
       master_table_id = (SELECT Id FROM master_table 
    WHERE 
       detail_table.old_master_table_id=master_table.OldId);
    ALTER TABLE detail_table DROP COLUMN old_master_table_id;
END
```

Although I have if and it works fine, Above command gives me error Invalid column name 'old_master_table_id'.

How can I avoid above error?

Comment: The problem is, SQL compiles that entire batch, based on the current database schema, before executing the `if`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try dynamic SQL. You will compile query in question only if applicable.

```
IF NOT Exists(SELECT * FROM sys.columns WHERE 
  Object_ID = Object_ID('detail_table') AND Name = 'old_master_table_id') BEGIN
    EXEC sp_executesql "UPDATE detail_table SET " +
    "                   master_table_id = (SELECT Id FROM master_table " +
    "                   WHERE " +
    "                   detail_table.old_master_table_id=master_table.OldId); " +
    "                   ALTER TABLE detail_table DROP COLUMN old_master_table_id; "
END
```